# Detecting non-dictionary words in messages

Tags: android

I need to check if the word is in the dictionary (correctly spelled) or not in dictionary (misspelled). Is there any bulit-in dictionary / spell checking function I can use to achieve this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

Comment: yeah i checked this it provides suggestions, i just wanna get true if spelling is correct, false for the other case. is there anyway ?

Comment: I found a way to get through it by myself downvoters :@.

Comment: What did your solution end up being?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [drill down](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/SuggestionsInfo.html#RESULT_ATTR_IN_THE_DICTIONARY) into the documentation referenced by Adam:

If the value of `getSuggestionsAttributes()` **is equal to 1** then

> The
>   requested word was found in the dictionary in the text service.

but if the value of `getSuggestionsAttributes()` **is not equal to 1** then you can safely assume that the requested word was not found in the dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

Android provides [Spelling Checker Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html).

Comment: yeah i checked this it provides suggestions, i just wanna get true if spelling is correct, false for the other case. is there anyway ?